# How to read the source HTLM code from a locally saved HTML file using Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new to HTML and beautiful soup. I am trying to read a locally saved HTML file in Python and I tested the following code:

```
with open(file_path) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

print(soup)
```

The output looks weird and here is a part of it:

```
<html><body><p>ÿþh t m l &gt; 
 
 
 
 h e a d &gt; 
 
 m e t a   h t t p - e q u i v = C o n t e n t - T y p e   c o n t e n t = " t e x t / h t m l ;   c h a r s e t = u n i c o d e " &gt; 
 
 m e t a   n a m e = G e n e r a t o r   c o n t e n t = " M i c r o s o f t   W o r d   1 5   ( f i l t e r e d ) " &gt; 
 
 s t y l e &gt; 
 
 ! - - 
 
   / *   F o n t   D e f i n i t i o n s   * /
```

The original HTML code is something like

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
```

Can anyone help me or share some thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's discuss why you are not able to `fetch` desired `Output`. It is because when you `parsing` data in `BeautifulSoup`. There might be some **Spaces, Symbols, etc.** presented in your `Code`. So, the appropriate `Solution` for this scenario was stated below:-

- **Needed Solution:-** Use `soup.prettify()`
- **Appropriate Solution:-** Use `HTML Parser` and `soup.prettify()` together

> To Learn more about `HTML Parser` and `soup.prettify`:- [Click Here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

---

#### Approach 1 (By using `soup.prettify()` in your Current `Code`):-

```
# File Path of 'HTML' File
file_path = 'demo.html'

# Fetch 'HTML' Code Using 'BeautifulSoup'
with open(file_path) as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

# Print 'HTML' Code using 'prettify' Format
print(soup.prettify())
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)" name="Generator"/>
  <style>
   <!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
  </style>
 </head>
</html>
```

---

#### Approach 2 (By using `HTML Parser` and `soup.prettify()`):-

```
# Import all-important Libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

# Open Our 'HTML' File
html_page = open('demo.html', 'r')

# Parse it to 'HTML' Format
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html5lib")

# Print Scraped 'HTML' Code
print(soup.prettify())
```

```
# Output of above cell:-
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)" name="Generator"/>
  <style>
   <!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
  </style>
 </head>
</html>
```

Hope this Solution helps you.

Comment: Thank you for providing two solutions! They're super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try `print(soup.prettify())`. The prettify method is helpful and displays the formatted HTML content.

According to the documentation:

> The prettify() method will turn a Beautiful Soup parse tree into a nicely formatted Unicode string, with a separate line for each tag and each string:

Source: [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing)